# combine two tables in mysql for recent activity functionality

Tags: php, mysql

In my page I have a tab named Recent activity, In which I have to display the two different types of actions

- Recently added choices
- Recently voted choices

The table stucture for je_addchoice

je_addpoll table

```
poll_id | user_id | poll_name | category_id | start_date | end_date

  1     |   20    |Naturalflrs|    18       | 2012-12-03 | 2095-12-25
```

je_addchoice table

```
choice_id | poll_id | choice_creator_id | choice_name | choice_image | description | ctime

     1    |    1    |        20         |  Greenish   | forest.jpg   | forest      |135453
```

je_user_vote table

```
vote_id | user_id | poll_id | choice_id | datetime_voted | user_type

  12    |  31     |    1    |   1       |12-12-2606:23:17|  normal
```

Already I have the result page displays as shown below

[image: The recently added choices are displayed]

The above result is displayed using the query

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM je_addchoice, je_addpoll where je_addpoll.start_date <= '$check_date' AND je_addpoll.end_date >='$check_date'  AND je_addpoll.poll_id=je_addchoice.poll_id order by je_addchoice.choicecreationtime desc");
```

The two tables

1) je_addpoll (Main table for polls)

2) je_addchoice (adding choices for the polls)

But what I want to do here is If any user votes for the poll, It will store into

je_user_vote table as shown above.

I want to display the recently voted choices in the same tab

Comment: How did you try combining the two tables and what result did you get?

Comment: I used left join query for combining these two tables but I got error in mysql query

Comment: explain your question in details ...

Comment: I want to display the choices which are recently added and also recently voted. But now I display the recently added only. How to show the recently voted choices in the same tab.

Comment: first of all let us know, your expected output and what you have tried.

Comment: instead of posting images poststructure and sample data of your tables so that it is easy to solve the problem

Comment: Can you please clearify your problem and post desired result

Comment: Yes. Sure. I will edit the post as understandable

Comment: The question is edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

use `desc` order for `datetime_voted` just before `je_addchoice.choicecreationtime desc`

like this.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT P.poll_id,P.user_id,P.poll_name,P.category_id,P.start_date,P.end_date,C.choice_id,C.choice_creator_id,C.choice_name,C.choice_image,C.description,C.ctime FROM je_addchoice C, je_addpoll P where P.start_date <= '$check_date' AND P.end_date >='$check_date'  AND P.poll_id=C.poll_id order by C.choicecreationtime desc) N,je_user_vote U WHERE U.poll_id=N.poll_id order by U.datetime_voted desc,N.choicecreationtime desc");
```

OR

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT N.poll_id,N.user_id,N.poll_name,N.category_id,N.start_date,N.end_date,N.choice_id,N.choice_creator_id,N.choice_name,N.choice_image,N.description,N.ctime FROM (SELECT P.poll_id,P.user_id,P.poll_name,P.category_id,P.start_date,P.end_date,C.choice_id,C.choice_creator_id,C.choice_name,C.choice_image,C.description,C.ctime FROM je_addchoice C, je_addpoll P where P.start_date <= '$check_date' AND P.end_date >='$check_date'  AND P.poll_id=C.poll_id order by C.choicecreationtime desc) N,je_user_vote U WHERE U.poll_id=N.poll_id order by U.datetime_voted desc,N.choicecreationtime desc");
```

Comment: The datetime_voted field is in table je_user_vote table. How to combine this I dont know. The current result is shown using two tables

je_addpoll(Using pollid as foreign key the choices are displayed for particular poll)
je_addchoice (Main table for poll)

Now I want to combine the je_user_vote table for recently voted

Comment: so, you mean , you want to combine 3 tables ??

Comment: Yes, already the two tables are combined to show the recently added. Now I want to combine the three tables for showing two actions

Recently added
Recently voted

Comment: let me know name of 3 tables.\

Comment: The question is edited now. Please take a look in my question

Comment: must mention, your final columns from 3 tables, i mean what are columns, you need, finally. That will make easy to write query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21700/discussion-between-rithu-and-var)

Comment: @Rithu first of all check my updated answer. If it doesn't work. Then we will move to chat. :)